# getting derived class by base pointer?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class

I could've sworn this worked some time ago when my object was declared on the heap instead of on the stack. I have a function that takes a pointer to a base class ( detail::DuplicateFn ). - Though as that is a virtual class the actual pointers are given by a derived class (ie dteail::SkipFn)

```
1>GMProject.cpp(298): error C2664:
'void xml_tree<V>::combine_if<bool(__cdecl *)(const T &,const T &)>(const xml_tree<V> &,Predicate,const detail::DuplicateFn *)' :
cannot convert parameter 3 from 'detail::SkipFn (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'const detail::DuplicateFn *'
```

My function:

```
void GMProject::CombineTree(const pTree& Other) {
    detail::SkipFn foo();
        ProjectTree.combine_if(Other, &SimilarTreeValue<GMProject::pTree>, &foo);
}
```

Where ProjectTree.combine_if() as third parameter requires a pointer to "DuplicateFn" - and SkipFn is derived from DuplicateFn.

As said this works (like I expect) correctly if I declare "foo" on the heap. However it doesn't when declaring foo on the stack (or -ultimatelly- making foo a temporary). Why is that?

Comment: See also ["Is there any difference between `List x;` and `List x();`?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.2) from the C++ FAQ and the [same](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ctors.html#fqa-10.2) from the C++ FQA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
detail::SkipFn foo();
```

`foo` is not an object. It's a function whose return type is `detail::SkipFn`. So, instead try -

```
detail::SkipFn foo;   // Notice the removal of (). Google most vexing parse 
                      // for explanation.
```

[Is there any difference between List x; and List x();?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.2)

Comment: Google "most vexing parse", you mean.

Comment: +1. I've never considered that ambiguity before, very interesting. You learn something every day :)

Comment: Argh - This must've been the 100th time I've been catched by this "problem". I know it very well Yet I keep falling to this mistake.